# Understanding React EventHandlers in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am a Java programmer, trying to learn ReactJS using Typescript. I am following an i[ntroductory tutorial on React/Typescript](https://medium.com/@dtkatz/react-hooks-tutorial-learn-by-building-b90ec4db2b8e) and got stuck understanding the `EventHandler` types for different user actions.

Here's an input field with `EventHandler`, that's a function `updateUserText` that takes accepts an Event and returns nothing.

```
<input value={userText} onChange={updateUserText}/>

const updateUserText = event => {
   setUserText(event.target.value);
}
```

Here's a button with `EventHandler` that's a function `chooseSnippet` that take a function that accepts an Event and returns another function.

```
<button onClick={chooseSnippet(2)}/>

const chooseSnippet = snippetIndex => () => {
  setSnippet(SNIPPETS[snippetIndex]);
};
```

For a beginner like me, it's difficult to understand what "type" is expected as a handler for different events. **How does one know that `onClick` requires returning another function, while `onChange` does not?** Looking at the function definition is not helping me.

```
onChange?: ChangeEventHandler<T>;
onClick?: MouseEventHandler<T>;
type ChangeEventHandler<T = Element> = EventHandler<ChangeEvent<T>>;
type MouseEventHandler<T = Element> = EventHandler<MouseEvent<T>>;
interface ChangeEvent<T = Element> extends SyntheticEvent<T> 
interface MouseEvent<T = Element, E = NativeMouseEvent> extends SyntheticEvent<T, E>
type EventHandler<E extends SyntheticEvent<any>> = { bivarianceHack(event: E): void }["bivarianceHack"];
```

Comment: Both onClick and onChange require functions. Executing chooseSnippet in place is returning a function (the callback handler) to onClick. The argument, `snippetIndex`, isn't an event, it's just an arbitrary value. It's a way to for the inner function to close over the value so that particular onclick selects the second element. Sort of like a factory for building functions

Comment: @Andy: Sorry, still can't follow. Let me rephrase - how do I avoid writing code like chooseSnippet = snippetIndex => { } and updateUserText = event => () => { }? I thought Typescript will help me avoid such errors that I am now discovering at runtime.

Comment: @AndyRay I re-read your comment and I think I understand you now. But this creates new doubts for me - EventHandler is a function of type (event: E)=>void. chooseSnippet(2) returns a function of type ()=>void. How is onClick accepting this argument?

Comment: I guess I hadn't thought about it, but typescript doesn't verify that you use/accept arguments, it only checks the types of arguments if you do accept them.